# Can't highlight line of zoomed tmux pane if pane border behind it

Tags: macos, tmux, terminal.app

**TL;DR: I can't highlight/select a line on a `Z` pane if, on the unzoomed window, there is a pane border behind that line**

I am using tmux 2.6, terminal.app, and High Sierra on a macbook pro (the touchbar one).

In tmux I can highlight most lines by clicking, holding, and dragging. Because I have

```
set -g mouse on
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "pbcopy"
```

it automatically will copy the highlighted text. This works great unless I can't highlight/select the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is a known issue](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1473) and will be fixed in the next release of tmux (2.9). Unfortunately, it hasn't been released yet, so I guess we're stuck with the problem for now.

Comment: Tmux 2.9 and beyond have this issue fixed, and they are now available!